# Floating Widget like Messenger on Google Site

Tags: javascript, html, css, floating-action-button, google-sites

Hi I am trying to make a floating widget like facebook messenger in google site but the problem is that it only stays at the very bottom on its section

here's my code

```
<html>
<style>
.UtePc #pingpilot{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #660000;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
<body>
<script id="pingpilot" type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.pingpilot.com/widget-button.js" data-signal="483c60" async></script>
</body>
<html>
```

[image]

When I scroll down to the very bottom it only stays there. What I want is that even if I scroll up it should still float where ever I scroll.

Comment: Check the *ping pilot button* with DevTools and you will see that you need to override the `#pingpilot-master-container` inline CSS rules. The same goes for `#pingpilot-widget` when you clicked the button and the chat window opens. Use `!important` on the various rules when overriding them doesn't seem to work...

Comment: it doesn't work even if i use !important. Is there a way on google drive to access its CSS??

Answer (score 1):

what you want is `position: fixed`, which places relative to the viewport.

Comment: the problem with this is that even if i used `position:fixed` it will just remain on it's section not on the whole page sir

Comment: @JustANoob fixed makes it stay where it is relative to the viewport, so if you scroll, it stays still. is that not what you want? something that stays in the bottom right of screen no matter where you scroll?